# Counting objects that contain specific property in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to read stats out of an array of objects that looks like this:

```
{
    "time":"19.09",
    "car":"429",
    "driver":"Julia",
    "from":"James Hotel",
    "destination":"Juba Teaching Hospital",
    "pax":"2",
    "arrival":"19.09",
    "inserted":true
}

{
    "date":"25/10/2014",
    "time":"19.11",
    "car":"396",
    "driver":"Tom",
    "from":"Drilling company",
    "destination":"James Hotel",
    "pax":"2",
    "comment":"This comment is a test",
    "commenttime":"19.11",
    "arrival":"19.12",
    "inserted":true
}
```

I'm using the Unique module from AngularUI to be able to make a list of all drivers or all cars, which so far works OK and creates the following table:

[image: table of stats]

```
<div class="row msf-stats-data-row" >
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="record in recordlist | unique:'car'">
      <div class="col-md-4">{{record.car}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">Trips</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">Time on the road</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
    <div class="row"   ng-repeat="record in recordlist | unique:'driver'">
      <div class="col-md-6">{{record.driver}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-2">Trips</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">Time on the road</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Every object is a trip. My problem right now is that I want to be able to both count how many objects contain each of the unique `record.car` or `record.driver` properties (to be able to determine how many trips a car took), and also to make operations with momentJS to be able to determine how much time a particular car or driver was on the road (timeOnRoad = record.time - record.arrival).

I'm a bit lost on whether this is even possible to do.

Any input?

**ANSWER**

The answer from Ilan worked perfectly! Here's my code after I adapted it slightly.

```
var carsDict = {};

angular.forEach($scope.recordlist, function(record) {
  carsDict[record.car] = carsDict[record.car] || [];
  carsDict[record.car].push(record);
});
$scope.carstats = carsDict;
```

And the HTML:

```
 <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="carcode in carstats">
          <div class="col-md-4">{{carcode[0].car}}</div> <!-- Car code -->
          <div class="col-md-4">{{carcode.length}}</div> <!-- Nº of objects (trips) inside carcode -->
          <div class="col-md-4">Time on the road</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Try adding a column in ng-repeat {{$index}}

Comment: @Linial can you expand on that? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't realize that you need to perform actions on those lists. anyway, in any ng-repeat scope you get those extra variables $index, $first, $last and so on. $index variable is simply referring to the index of the specific ng-repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a dictionary of cars to store references of records per car.

```
var carsDict = {};

angular.forEach(recordlist, function(record) {
  carsDict[record.car] = carsDict[record.car] || [];
  carsDict[record.car].push(record);
});
```

Then you can make all calculations for each car.

Comment: I have a list of cars, but the cars can be added or removed, and I want to be able to also read stats about cars that are no longer on the list, therefore I'm reading from the records list and not from the cars list.

Comment: @EricMitjans I only touched the records list

Comment: I got your code to work (See updated question)! Many thanks for that! The only problem is that I don't really understand your function. Care to explain? Thanks again!